# How to call a Form inside a TTask (Thread)?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

In Delphi 10 I have a `FormA` that calls an Oracle stored procedure inside a  iTask (thread) "Tarefaproc". This storedproc updates a table that will be used by a `Tchart` in another `FormB`.

I'm calling `FormB` just after this `iTask` Tarefaproc but,  it is not working, it is frozen the application !!  I appreciate your help to understand and solve this issue.

See my code :

```
procedure TFormA.SpeedButtonChamaGrafico(Sender: TObject);
var
   Tarefaproc, Tarefagrafico : iTask;
begin

// Call StoredProc inside iTask ==>  this WORKS PERFECTLY !!

Tarefaproc := TTask.Create( procedure ()
                            begin
                                 with FDStoredProc1 do
                                 begin
                                      Prepare;
                                      Params[0].Value := StrToInt(EditCenario.Text);
                                      Execproc;
                                  end;
                             end);
          Tarefaproc.Start;

// Next, calls FormB inside another iTASK ==> DOESN'T WORK , it frozes the application !

 Tarefagrafico := TTask.Create(
                              procedure ()
                              begin
                                   try
                                      Application.CreateForm(TformB,FormB);
                                      FormB.ShowModal;
                                   finally
                                      Freeandnil(formB);
                                   end;
                              end);
  Tarefagrafico.Start;
end;
```

Comment: You can't call the VCL from a thread without synchronizing. And you need to realize that both tasks will be executed in parallel.

Comment: This topic has been covered many many times here. Do some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the VCL from a thread is not possible.
Instead, [queue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) the method invoking the modal form for later execution in the main thread.

```
procedure TFormA.SpeedButtonChamaGrafico(Sender: TObject);
var
  value : Integer;
begin
  value := StrToInt(EditCenario.Text); // Avoid vcl access from thread !!
  TTask.Create( 
    procedure
      begin
        with FDStoredProc1 do
        begin
          Prepare;
          Params[0].Value := value;
          Execproc;
        end;
        // Next, queue method for later execution in main thread 
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          var
            FormB : TFormB; // Use local form variable
          begin
            FormB := TFormB.Create(nil);  // Way to create form dynamically
            try
              // Here you can add data into FormB from the database extraction !!
              // It is safe, since this call is executing in the main thread. 
              FormB.ShowModal;
            finally
              Freeandnil(FormB);
            end;
          end);
      end).Start;
end;
```

Note that even reading vcl properties from a thread is dangerous.
Also, using global form variables should be shunned. First thing on my to do list when creating a form from the IDE, is to delete the created global form variable.

---

From the documentation of `TThread.Queue`:

> Executes a method call within the main thread.
>   Queue causes the call specified by AMethod to be asynchronously executed using the main thread, thereby avoiding multi-thread conflicts.

Comment: Thks for the tips and solution. I implemented it , but there is still an issue with TThread.Queue because  it is taking some time to call FormB and before it appears, it is presenting a dialog error : '' is not a valid integer value.  I checked the value of variable "value" and  it has a valid number before to go to TThread !

Comment: @JRG You did not say which line is triggering the error, but I guess it is this statement: `StrToInt(EditCenario.Text)`, and the reason is that `EditCenario.Text` is empty.

Comment: Tom , this line is ok, I checked the contents and it EditCenario is filled with a valid number and the conversion to variable "value" is also ok.

Comment: JRG, the error is in code we cannot see. The above works fine in my test application. You have to debug your code harder to find the error.

Comment: JRG, The code I pointed at is the only one, in the presented code, that can trigger that error, and only if `EditCenario.Text` is empty. The value of `value` variable has nothing to do with that error message.

Comment: JRG, the issue with the time lapse is due to the time it takes for the thread to do its work with `Prepare/ExecProc`. My guess is that the error you are seeing is connected with how parameters are initialized in your `FormB`. My advice is to forward the data through `FormB` methods before you call `ShowModal`.

Comment: @LU RD, it seems your "guess" regarding the parameter passing from FormA to FormB is RIGHT . In fact the EditCenario field, besides to be used as a parameter to FDStoredProc1 , it is also acessed by FormB in the following way :  FormB.Editinputcenario .text := FormA.EditCenario.text.  This is the point that is generating the error!  Why FormB could not access a value in FormA when it is opened inside a Thread ?  Is this the right way to pass parameters between forms? Thanks for your valuable attention!

Comment: JRG, glad you found the problem, even though I cannot explain how it happens. But generally from a programming point of view, FormB should not be directly coupled to FormA. Instead as I said, feed all parameters FormB needs via one or several methods of FormB. (And I hope you took heed on my remark regarding using global form variables).

Comment: JRG, I see that on another question of yours, you are explicitly using form variables inside form methods, even if the form variable is of the same form type. This is all wrong and will only lead to disaster. Stop doing that!

Comment: @LU RD, for sure I took into consideration your advices regarding global variables.  I'm studying this moment how to adopt the best practices of OO and adopt the usage of properties and methods to communicates among forms.   Thanks for  your valuable knowledge sharing with me !

Comment: Great, I wish you all the best!